# PHP used with AJAX returns empty value instead of the desired results. (scope issues perhaps)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I am using AJAX file upload with PHP (and Laravel).

After the file is uploaded (it's a CSV), the script processes it then it should return an array.

```
Route::post('uploadcsv', 'CSVController@uploadCSV');
```

```
class CSVController extends \BaseController {

public function processFile($filePath, $fileType)
{
    // return 'test'; // works

    Excel::load($filePath, function($reader)
    {
        return 'test'; // returns empty
        $results = $reader->get();
        return $results; // returns empty too
    });
}

public function uploadCSV()
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    if (Input::hasFile('importCSV') && Input::file('importCSV')->isValid())
    {
        $file = Input::file('importCSV');

        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        if ($extension === 'csv' || $extension === 'txt')
        {
            $name = $user->username . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
            $file->move(public_path() . '/uploads/', $name);
        }
        else
        {
            return 'fail';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 'fail';
    }

    $processFileResponse = $this->processFile(public_path() . '/uploads/' . $name, $extension);

    return $processFileResponse;
}
}
```

My AJAX looks like:

```
$('#importCSVSubmit').on('click', function () {
    var formElement = document.getElementById('importCSVForm');
    var formData = new FormData(formElement);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'uploadcsv',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (response, textStatus, xhr) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log(textStatus); // returns 'success'
            console.log(xhr.error.length); // returns 0
        }
    });
});
```

However, when I'm using the code in the function processFile directly and load a demo page directly, it works and I can see the results of the Excel::load function.

The path ($filePath) is proper in every cases (working demo and non-working "ajax/php".)

You can see the lines with `// return 'test';` and their comments, I used for trying to debug.

I'm guessing scope could be the problem, played around with that too (declared $results as global before the Excel::load())

Comment: Does the success return anything? Try adding in `error`. And check your apache and your laravel log.

Comment: console.log(xhr.error.length); returns 0. I checked the laravel.log and it seems fine. I'm running the server with php directly without apache I can't see any log in the php folder about it.

Comment: even `  function test() {
   return 'test';
  }

  test();` doesnt return 'test'

Comment: If I add `return` infront of test() then it works. I tried adding `return` infront of Excel::load but it generates a 500 error.

Comment: I get undefined variable filePath when inside Excel::load

Comment: You trying to access `$filePath` inside `Excel::load()`?

Comment: Actually no just trying to debug and for sure I can't access filePath inside load() unless it's global.

Comment: I opened a new more abstracted question about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290491/cannot-convert-object-to-string-returning-a-function

Comment: Simply had to declare global $results a couple of times.

Answer (score 1):

I only had to declare `global $results;` inside processFile and inside Excel::load() and then I could return $results at the end of the processFile function.

```
public function processFile($filePath, $fileType)
{
    global $results;
    Excel::load($filePath, function($reader)
    {
        global $results;
        $results = $reader->get();
    });
    return $results;
}
```