# Cannot convert object to string. Returning a function

Tags: php

I need to return the response of a function and I get an error

```
function excel() {

    // If I don't add return here, then calling excel() will always be empty.
    // However when calling it I get the error ErrorException

    return Excel::load($filePath, function($reader) {
        $results = $reader->get();
        return $results; // there's an array here
    });
}

function test() {
  return excel();
}

return test(); //Empty when it should have an array.

message: "Object of class Maatwebsite\Excel\Readers\LaravelExcelReader could not be converted to string"
type: "ErrorException"
```

How can I properly achieve what I want? (which at the end is to return $results).

Edit:
The error is thrown from a file being used in Laravel, which is:

Line 406 
`file: "/App/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php"`

And the code under the hood there is

```
public function setContent($content)
{
    if (null !== $content && !is_string($content) && !is_numeric($content) && !is_callable(array($content, '__toString'))) {
        throw new \UnexpectedValueException(sprintf('The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "%s" given.', gettype($content)));
    }

    $this->content = (string) $content;

    return $this;
}
```

No idea why it goes through that code, need some suggestions.

Comment: So, where is the line where this error message occurs?

Comment: In the Chrome developer tool under "network" (this function is being called through POST). adding to my post.

Comment: "Cannot convert to string" means you're trying to treat an object like a string at some point when the object doesn't support that, e.g. `echo $object`. It has nothing to do with `return`.

Comment: Well, and there you have it, `(string)$content`. You need to turn your object into something that behaves like a string first, otherwise Laravel doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: Thank deceze. That helped. I don't know why some angry dummies down vote a question in which I am receiving useful help from people like you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, I had to use json_encode this way:

```
return json_encode(Excel::load($filePath, function($reader) {
    $results = $reader->get();
    return $results; // there's an array here
}));
```

"Cannot convert object to string." was key in answering my own question (had to do some googling for a while).

Answer (score 0):

```
function excel() {
return Excel::load($filePath)->get();}
```

Comment: The question deserves a more comprehensive answer